# How to approach, substitution - definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have this problem 
$${\int^{\pi/2}_0} {{\cos\theta \sin\theta}\over \sqrt{\cos^{2}\theta +8}}d\theta  $$

and I'm not sure if this is the right direction to begin. If I have $u = \cos\theta$ then,  $du = -\sin\theta$ can I then do this:

$$-du=\sin\theta$$
$$-\cos\theta du = \cos\theta \sin\theta dx$$ and then: 
$$-\cos\theta {{\int^{0}_1}} {1\over \sqrt{u}}du$$
$$=\cos\theta {{\int^{1}_0}} {1\over \sqrt{u}}du$$

And then do the rest from there? 
Also, what other way could I do this?

Comment: You have a $\sin 2\theta$ in the numerator and a $\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2 \theta - 1$ expression in the denominator .. (btw is it a typo or did you just pull out a $\cos \theta$ from inside the integral ? ! :O )

Comment: Let $u=\cos^2\theta+8$.

Comment: @r9m yea the $cos\theta$ that was pulled out would later be multiplied back to all the terms inside.

Comment: @stuntstool ah ! fine then :)

Comment: final answer i have after doing what @AndréNicolas suggested is $9^{1/2} - 8^{1/2}$

Comment: That's right. One might prefer calling it $3-2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You can't pull out the $\cos \theta$! That is not a constant.

Comment: @Dylan hmm so in $(2cos\theta - cos\theta)$ the $cos\theta$ is multiplying $-1 and 2$, if that's the case can't you factor out a $cos\theta$? Because it's a definite integral and I have to do ${\int^{b}_a} u(b)-u(a)$ can't I just pull out the anything that could be multiplying both terms and later multiply it back in?

Comment: No, you can't do that. $\cos \theta$ is part of the integrand and depends on $\theta$. You can only pull out constants, or things that do not depend on $\theta$. If you substitute you have to express $\cos \theta$ in terms of $u$. In your case the integral is actually
$$\int_0^1 \frac{u}{\sqrt{u}} du = \int_0^1 \sqrt{u} \,du$$

Comment: @Dylan Idk then, that's how I do it and when all else is done correctly, the answer is also correct doing as I described. I'm not very math-y so I'm not sure how to describe what I'm reasoning in my head but. $${\int^{b}_a} f(x)dx $$ is going to equal the antiderivative of $f$ from $b-a$ so, $${\int^{b}_a} f(x)dxh$$ where h = something will equal the antiderivative of $$f(b)*h-f(a)*h$$ ??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you continue your above method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to note that the numerator is a constant times the derivative of expression within the square root in the denominator, i.e.
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}(\cos^2\theta+8)=-2\cos\theta\sin\theta$$
so that the indefinite integral is simply
$$-(\cos^2\theta+8)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ 
You can verify this by differentiating the above, using the chain rule.

Comment: Good answer.  +1